# Represent time with many maps and standard graduation

Tags: qgis, style

I want to represent trends over time.

So I have 4 diferent maps (e.g. 95' 00' 05' 10') but my problem is in graduation.

Is there any form to make the graduation with standars breaks and colors (e.g. in all of the maps 30-60 to be red, 60 to 90 to be blue etc)

I read many post like that one:
 https://www.gislounge.com/time-and-gis/ 
but i couldnt found my answer.

Comment: Tell us a bit more about your data - perhaps some screen captures - are you using points, polygons, lines, maybe all geometry types?